# Java CharAt() and deleteCharAt() performance

Tags: java, performance, string, complexity-theory, stringbuilder

I've been wondering about the implementation of `charAt` function for `String/StringBuilder/StringBuffer` in java
what is the complexity of that ?
also what about the `deleteCharAt()` in `StringBuffer/StringBuilder` ?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the source code for these methods?

Comment: Yeah, since you already got a linux system at your disposal, you should grab open-JDK and explore it yourself.

Comment: @HoverCraft I just did check the source .. thanks for pointing me to that
@Mazyod .. ok

Comment: If ever you think you need a thread safe StringBuffer, you probably have a poor design (or you could use another class like StringWriter)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For `String`, `StringBuffer`, and `StringBuilder`, `charAt()` is a constant-time operation.

For `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder`, `deleteCharAt()` is a linear-time operation.

`StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` have very similar performance characteristics. The primary difference is that the former is `synchronized` (so is thread-safe) while the latter is not.

Comment: *For String, deleteCharAt() is an O(n) operation, where n is the size of the string* String is immutable and cannot delete anything (no such function), deleteCharAt for StringBuffer/Builder it's an array code `System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);` while memmove can be impl. with the help of the hardware it's still O(n) technically.

Comment: I'm an idiot for not realizing the non-existence of `String#deleteCharAt()`. Thanks.

Comment: @sleeparrow Java isn't JS; internally Java uses UTF-16, not UTF-8. If you read the source code for the various methods, it's pretty clear that, for example, `charAt()` is a constant-time operation because it's simply indexing into a `char` array. [`String#charAt(int)`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#691) and [`StringBuilder#charAt(int)`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.html#201)

Comment: ha, I didn't realize this was a Java question. excuse me.

Comment: @MattBall But UTF-16 isn't constant size either, so although charAt will still work in constant time, for characters that need 32 bits, operation will only return half of the real character

Answer (score 30):

Let us just look at the corresponding actual java implementation(only relevant code) for each of these methods in turn. That itself will answer about their efficiency.

## String.charAt :

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

As we can see, it is just a single array access which is a **constant time** operation.

## StringBuffer.charAt :

```
public synchronized char charAt(int index) {
  if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
  return value[index];
}
```

Again, single array access, so a **constant time** operation.

## StringBuilder.charAt :

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    return value[index];
}
```

Again, single array access, so a **constant time** operation. Even though all these three methods look same, there are some minor differences. For example, only StringBuffer.charAt method is synchronized but not other methods. Similarly **if check** is slightly different for String.charAt (guess why?). Closer look at these method implementations itself give us other minor differences among them.

Now, let us look at deleteCharAt implementations.

String does not have deleteCharAt method. The reason might be it is an immutable object. So exposing an API which explicitly indicates that this method modifies the object is not  probably a good idea.

Both StringBuffer and StringBuilder are subclasses of AbstractStringBuilder. The deleteCharAt method of these two classes is delegating the implementation to its parent class itself.

## StringBuffer.deleteCharAt :

```
  public synchronized StringBuffer deleteCharAt(int index) {
        super.deleteCharAt(index);
        return this;
    }
```

## StringBuilder.deleteCharAt :

```
 public StringBuilder deleteCharAt(int index) {
        super.deleteCharAt(index);
        return this;
    }
```

## AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt :

```
  public AbstractStringBuilder deleteCharAt(int index) {
        if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        System.arraycopy(value, index+1, value, index, count-index-1);
        count--;
        return this;
    }
```

A closer look at AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt method reveals that it is actually calling System.arraycopy. This can be O(N) in worst case. So deleteChatAt method is O(N)  time complexity.

Answer (score 8):

The `charAt` method is `O(1)`.

The `deleteCharAt` method on `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` is `O(N)` on average, assuming you are deleting a random character from an `N` character `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder`.  (It has to move, on average, half of the remaining characters to fill up the "hole" left by the deleted character.  There is *no amortization over multiple operations*; see below.)  However, if you delete the last character, the cost will be `O(1)`.

There is no `deleteCharAt` method for `String`.

---

In theory, `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` could be optimized for the case where you are inserting or deleting multiple characters in a "pass" through the buffer.  They could do this by maintaining an optional "gap" in the buffer, and moving characters across it.  (IIRC, emacs implements its text buffers this way.)  The problems with this approach are:

- It requires more space, for the attributes that say where the gap is, and for the gap itself.
- It makes the code a lot more complicated, and slows down other operations.  For instance, `charAt` would have to compare the `offset` with the start and end points of the gap, and make the corresponding adjustments to the actual index value before fetching the character array element.
- It is only going to help if the application does multiple inserts / deletes on the same buffer.

Not surprisingly, this "optimization" has not been implemented in the standard `StringBuilder` / `StringBuffer` classes.  However, a custom `CharSequence` class could use this approach.

Answer (score 6):

`charAt` is super fast (and can use intrinsics for String), it's a simple index into an array. `deleteCharAt` would require an arraycopy, thus deleting a char won't be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Since we all know that the string is implemented in JDK as a character array, which implements the `randomAccess` interface. Therefore the time complexity of `charAt` should be int O(1). As other arrays, the delete operation has the `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of all responses from above:
charAt is O(1) since its just accessing the index of an array
deleteCharAt can be O(N) in worst case since it copies the entire array for it.