# How to merge two String into one String in java

Tags: java

Suppose:

```
String s1="13579";
String s2="2468";
```

then output would be `123456789`

Here my code :

```
public class JoinString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "13579"; 
        String s2 = "2468";
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < s2.length(); j++) {

                System.out.print(s1.charAt(i) + "" + s2.charAt(j));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your reasoning for that `break`?

Comment: You don't really need two nested loops there. Just one loop that keeps track of an index into both strings is sufficient. Once you've run out of the shorter one, you can just append a substring of the longer one based on how far into it you've gotten.

Comment: if i didnt use break statement, then op will be 12141618343638565878 .

Comment: s1.concat(s2) ....

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar won't work, since the OP is trying to interweave the strings, not append one to the other.

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar, according to you logic. o/p will be 135792468

Comment: your code is work fine

Comment: @azurefrog, can you show me logic. as in above code. it is not printing last char of s1 i.e 9.

Comment: @PrashantGaurav Go look at Roman's answer.  It doesn't even need the fix after the loop, since it's clever with the termination condition.

Comment: Does output need to be sorted? Or interleaved? It's unclear.

Comment: @PrashantGaurav If `s1="97531"` and `s2="2468"`, what output would you expect? `123456789` or `927456381`?

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++) {
    if (i < s1.length()) {
        buf.append(s1.charAt(i));
    }
    if (i < s2.length()) {
        buf.append(s2.charAt(i));
    }
}
final String result = buf.toString();
```

You only need one loop. Also, you can use a `StringBuilder` class to build your string character by character.

Answer (score 3):

How about this little trick:

```
String s1 = "13579"; 
String s2 = "2468";

String s3 = (s1 + s2).codePoints() // stream of code points
    .sorted()
    // collect into StringBuilder
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,  StringBuilder::append) 
    .toString();

System.out.println(s3); // 123456789
```

Comment: But that only works if the inputs are strictly sorted.  Can we really assume that's always the case?

Comment: @azurefrog I was just wondering about that. tbh I thought that was the whole point, to get sorted output.

Comment: Hmm, good point, looking back at it, the OP's question could be read as "every other character" or "sorted output", it's sort of ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to achieve that is by doing something like this:

```
String s1 = "13579"; 
String s2 = "2468";
char[]result = (s1+s2).toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
123456789
```

Comment: But that only works if the inputs are strictly sorted. Can we really assume that's always the case?

Comment: @azurefrog What do you mean by *strictly sorted*?, I used the example the OP mentioned.

Comment: True, see my reply on @Jorn Vernee's answer.  The OP's question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to combine the logic of the two loops like this (and use StringBuilder if you want to build a string this way).

```
    String s1 = "13579"; 
    String s2 = "2468";
    int length = Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(i < s1.length())
          System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));

        if(i < s2.length())
          System.out.print(s2.charAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: This might be a little redundant with the double checking of `s1.length()` and `s2.length()`.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi true... Broke out that bit so that the while loop does minimal work on while part.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Roman Puchovskiy, here is a way to do it without the `StringBuilder`.

```
    String s1 = "abcde";
    String s2 = "defgh";
    String combined = "";
    int length = s1.length() > s2.length() ? s1.length() : s2.length(); //Finds the longest length of the two, to ensure no chars go missing
    for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        if(i < s1.length()) { // Make sure there is a char in s1 where we're looking.
            combined += s1.charAt(i);
        }
        if(i < s2.length()) { // Same with s2.
            combined += s2.charAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Where `combined` becomes the combined string. (`"adbecfdgeh"`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please note that this will produce a lot of garbage: a string object per `+=`, so an object per resulting string character. A GC may not be happy.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy thanks for the insight, I wasn't aware that this was the case. However, I did just read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323132/4914803) that it may not matter, because Java's compiler is smart enough to turn it to a `StringBuilder`. Either way, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisGilardi the compiler does do that, but then `toString` is called each time the loop runs, while with a `StringBuilder`, that happens only once. May not be noticiable here, but this does take more memory than a `StringBuilder` solution. For single statement, it doesn't matter. But within loops, it makes a considerable difference.

Comment: @ChandlerBing Well alrighty, I stand corrected! Thanks for letting me know, I'll remember that for my own projects!

Comment: @ChrisGilardi No worries :) I also recommend reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47758/5055190

Answer (score 0):

Similar way as merge method in merge sort.

Also it's better if you convert string to char array so that random access to element is in constant time.
Because charAt has O(n) time complexity.

```
public class JoinString {

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    String s1 = "13579";
    String s2 = "2468";
    final char[] str1 = s1.toCharArray();
    final char[] str2 = s2.toCharArray();
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < str1.length && i < str2.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.print( str1[i] + "" + str2[i] );
    }

    while ( i < str1.length ) {
        System.out.print( str1[i] + "" );
        i++;
    }

    while ( i < str2.length ) {
        System.out.print( str2[i] + "" );
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For `String`, `StringBuffer`, and `StringBuilder`, `charAt()` is a constant-time operation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461402/java-charat-and-deletecharat-performance