# balanced parantheses recursive method in scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I am working through functional programming in scala and am a bit stumped on trying to write a recursive method to find balanced parentheses.

DISCLAIMER - I am not looking for a copy/paste answer, I am just hoping someone can point out why my conditional statements are not evaluating (I am very new to scala so the idea that conditional are themselves expressions is a new concept for me).

Here is my attempt so far:

```
  def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    val charStack = new Stack[Char]()

    def balanceRec(chars: List[Char]):  Boolean = {
      if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty

      println(chars.mkString(", "))
      if (chars.head == ')' &&
          charStack.isEmpty
        ) {
          false
      }
      else if (chars.head == ')' &&
        charStack.pop() != '('
      )  {
        false
      }

      else{
        if(chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
        balanceRec(chars.tail)
      }


    }
    balanceRec(chars)

  }
```

I am testing on a very simple input like `val chars = List('(', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ')', 'a')` and even still get a `java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list`.

I am confused on why my second `else if` statement is not firing to return `false`. Also, I have fleshed out these conditions to ensure I understand they work as I think they do - please don't make fun of me :)

Comment: Because your conditions are not connected into a single expression. For example, the first `if` is separated from everything else, and the second group of `ifs` doesn't have a final `else`. I would recommend you to use pattern matching instead, but you can just fix this by joining all the ifs in a single expression or using `return` _([not recommended](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html))_. - Also, try to solve this problem without any mutability, it should be pretty simple to keep your stack in your recursive function as another **List**.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. I actually just realized the issue a moment ago, but  I will certainly try to do away with the mutable structure as well as pattern matching. Thanks :)

Comment: @MasonEdmison take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894698/time-and-space-complexity-using-tail-recursion) :)

Comment: "I am very new to scala so the idea that conditional are themselves expressions is a new concept for me" – May I ask what languages you are used to? Because e.g. C, C++, Java, C#, ECMAScript, PHP, and many others have the *conditional operator* (`?`/`:`), which is an expression, Python has a conditional expression, Ruby has both the conditional operator, *and* also `if` is an expression as well. So, it's not a very unique concept at all.

Comment: @JörgWMittag. In python you can have a single `if` statement with no corresponding `else`. I have gotten in the habit of checking for degenerate cases this way: 
`if varA is None: return None; if varA == "varA": return "varA"; else: "some other variable name"`

Comment: But that's an `if` *statement*, not a conditional *expression*. In [Python's conditional *expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/2988) (`a if condition else b`), you cannot leave out the `else`, as far as I know. In Ruby, you *can*, but of course, it still needs to have a value, so its value is `nil`. In Scala, you also can, but then its value will be `()` (pronounced "unit") and its type will be `Unit`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by cleaning up a little to make it easier what is going on.

The error is clearly within `balanceRec`, so we don't even need to look at `balance`:

```scala
def balanceRec(chars: List[Char]):  Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty

  println(chars.mkString(", "))
  if (chars.head == ')' &&
      charStack.isEmpty
    ) {
      false
  }
  else if (chars.head == ')' &&
    charStack.pop() != '('
  )  {
    false
  }

  else{
    if(chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
    balanceRec(chars.tail)
  }


}
```

Next, the `println` clearly is not part of the problem either, so let's remove that:

```scala
def balanceRec(chars: List[Char]):  Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty

  if (chars.head == ')' &&
      charStack.isEmpty
    ) {
      false
  }
  else if (chars.head == ')' &&
    charStack.pop() != '('
  )  {
    false
  }

  else{
    if(chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
    balanceRec(chars.tail)
  }


}
```

Further, let's remove some unnecessary parentheses and clean up the white space and indentation:

```scala
def balanceRec(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty

  if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.isEmpty) false
  else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.pop() != '(') false
  else {
    if (chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
    balanceRec(chars.tail)
  }
}
```

Now the structure of the method becomes much clearer.

We notice now, that the first expression is a NO-OP: it has no side-effects, it doesn't mutate anything, it doesn't print anything, its result is not returned, its result is not printed, its result is not assigned to a variable or field. It literally does nothing at all.

That's the main problem.

As it turns out, *all* we need to do to fix the problem is insert one single `else` keyword before the second `if`:

```scala
def balanceRec(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty
  else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.isEmpty) false
  else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.pop() != '(') false
  else {
    if (chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
    balanceRec(chars.tail)
  }
}
```

[[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/bYvPNgr9RVGHlqhE5eq8UA)]

And since the body of our method is now a single expression, we can get rid of the curly braces:

```scala
def balanceRec(chars: List[Char]): Boolean =
  if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty
  else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.isEmpty) false
  else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.pop() != '(') false
  else {
    if (chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
    balanceRec(chars.tail)
  }
```

Finally, some general tips.

You are not actually using any of the specific features of [`List`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) in your code, you are only using the more general features of [`Seq`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html), in fact, you are actually only using features of [`Iterable`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html). I prefer to keep my interfaces as generic and as general as possible, so I would change the type here to `Iterable`:

```scala
def balance(chars: Iterable[Char]): Boolean = {
  val charStack = new Stack[Char]()

  def balanceRec(chars: Iterable[Char]): Boolean =
    if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty
    else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.isEmpty) false
    else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.pop() != '(') false
    else {
      if (chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
      balanceRec(chars.tail)
    }

  balanceRec(chars)
}
```

Next, I find the method awkward to use, because I have to pass in a collection of individual characters, when I would find it more natural to pass in a string:

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  val charStack = new Stack[Char]()

  def balanceRec(chars: Iterable[Char]): Boolean =
    if (chars.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty
    else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.isEmpty) false
    else if (chars.head == ')' && charStack.pop() != '(') false
    else {
      if (chars.head == '(') charStack.push(chars.head)
      balanceRec(chars.tail)
    }

  balanceRec(s.toIterable)
}
```

But actually, `String` supports `head` and `tail` as well, so there is no need to use the `Iterable` here:

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  val charStack = new Stack[Char]()

  def balanceRec(s: String): Boolean =
    if (s.isEmpty) charStack.isEmpty
    else if (s.head == ')' && charStack.isEmpty) false
    else if (s.head == ')' && charStack.pop() != '(') false
    else {
      if (s.head == '(') charStack.push(s.head)
      balanceRec(s.tail)
    }

  balanceRec(s)
}
```

I also prefer to use factory methods over constructors, so I would initialize the stack like this:

```scala
val charStack = Stack.empty[Char]
```

In functional programming, unlike many other communities, short variable names are perfectly acceptable, as long as the code still stays readable. Also, we generally trust our types, so for example, you don't have to say `charStack`: we *know* it's a stack, because it has type `Stack`! A typical naming pattern for naming a collection of things is to just append an `s` to denote the plural, so we could denote this `chars` or even just `cs` (which, as a happy coincidence, could alternatively be read as an abbreviation of "char stack").

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  val cs = Stack.empty[Char]

  def balanceRec(s: String): Boolean =
    if (s.isEmpty) cs.isEmpty
    else if (s.head == ')' && cs.isEmpty) false
    else if (s.head == ')' && cs.pop() != '(') false
    else {
      if (s.head == '(') cs.push(s.head)
      balanceRec(s.tail)
    }

  balanceRec(s)
}
```

Now that we have shortened the code quite a bit, we notice that the second and third alternative (the first two `else`s) have the same consequence: they both evaluate to `false`. So, we can simply connect their conditions with an OR:

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  val cs = Stack.empty[Char]

  def balanceRec(s: String): Boolean =
    if (s.isEmpty) cs.isEmpty
    else if (s.head == ')' && cs.isEmpty || s.head == ')' && cs.pop() != '(') false
    else {
      if (s.head == '(') cs.push(s.head)
      balanceRec(s.tail)
    }

  balanceRec(s)
}
```

Now we can apply some Boolean algebra and factor out the `s.head =='('` condition:

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  val cs = collection.mutable.Stack.empty[Char]

  def balanceRec(s: String): Boolean =
    if (s.isEmpty) cs.isEmpty
    else if (s.head == ')' && (cs.isEmpty || cs.pop() != '(')) false
    else {
      if (s.head == '(') cs.push(s.head)
      balanceRec(s.tail)
    }

  balanceRec(s)
}
```

Lastly, there is no need to have a mutable accumulator to pass information between different recursive calls, because the language already gives us tools that allow us to pass information into and out of calls: arguments and return values!

So, instead of keeping our state information in a mutable stack, we can simply pass an *immutable stack* (and we are simply going to use a `List` for this) along as an argument and return it as a value:

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  def balanceRec(s: String, cs: List[Char] = Nil): (Boolean, List[Char]) =
    if (s.isEmpty) (cs.isEmpty, cs)
    else if (s.head == ')' && cs.isEmpty || s.head == ')' && cs.head != '(') (false, cs)
    else balanceRec(s.tail, if (s.head == '(') s.head :: cs else cs)

  balanceRec(s)._1
}
```

Note that unlike what I said above, we are using `List[Char]` here instead of `Seq[Char]`, `Iterable[Char]`, or `String`, because in this case we *do* make use of one of the features of `List`, namely O(1) prepend, head, and tail, which neither of the other three guarantee.

**!!! Also note that this code is WRONG !!!**

We did not account for the fact that your original code used *side-effects*, more precisely, *mutation*. For example, the second branch, **even if it is not taken**, may still lead to `pop()`ping the top element of the stack. Let me repeat that: a branch that is *not taken* nevertheless changes the result.

In particular, if `s.head == ')'` is `true` and `cs.isEmpty` is `false` and `cs.head != '('` is `false` (in other words, `cs.head == '('` is `true`), then we `pop()` the top-most element, and even though we are not taking this branch, this mutation is still visible in the later branches of the `if` / `else` chain as well as future recursive calls.

So, we would have to account for that, in similar way as we accounted in the final `else`:

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  def balanceRec(s: String, cs: List[Char] = Nil): (Boolean, List[Char]) =
    if (s.isEmpty) (cs.isEmpty, cs)
    else if (s.head == ')' && cs.isEmpty) (false, cs)
    else if (s.head == ')' && cs.head != '(') (false, cs.tail)
    else if (s.head == ')' && cs.head == '(') balanceRec(s.tail, if (s.head == '(') s.head :: cs.tail else cs.tail)
    else balanceRec(s.tail, if (s.head == '(') s.head :: cs else cs)
  balanceRec(s)._1
}
```

Now, you might look at this, and say: "I thought functional programming is supposed to be so simple and so beautiful, but all I see here is that when we converted the mutable solution to an immutable one, it became a convoluted mess of triply-nested logic". But here's the thing: the mutable version had *exactly that same mess*! You were just not seeing it, because the dependencies between the different parts of the code that were connected by the mutable stack, were invisible. But they were still there.

As an alternative solution, note that we do not actually need to know the content of the stack at all. We only need to know how deep the stack is! So, we could instead do something like this:

```scala
def balance(s: String): Boolean = {
  def balanceRec(cs: List[Char], depth: Int = 0): Int =
    if (depth < 0) depth
    else cs match {
      case Nil       => depth
      case '(' :: cs => balanceRec(cs, depth + 1)
      case ')' :: cs => balanceRec(cs, depth - 1)
      case c :: cs   => balanceRec(cs, depth)
    }

  balanceRec(s.toList) == 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I particularly like the `depth:Int` solution. I have adapted my code to use this to both do away with the mutable stack (seems frowned upon to use mutable data structures in scala) and to simply the code :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out that recursion is not always needed, and sometimes recursion is not the most functional way to do something.

If all we desire is to determine whether or not parentheses are balanced, we simply want to know if there are the same number of `(` and `)`.

EDIT: This forgets to take into account that `)(` would return true, although it is invalid! I have updated the response to account for this.

To address this, we can take into account that the running total must always be greater than zero

We can use `map` to transform the list of `Char`s into a list of `Int`s

We can transform a `(` into a `+1`, a `)` into a `-1`, and all other characters we don't care about and can turn them to `0`

To check for balance, the sum of our new list should be `0`, and the value should never fall below zero

To achieve this, we can use the `foldLeft` operator, which takes two parameter lists

```scala
val testList: List[Char] = List('(', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g', ')', '!')
    
val mappedList: List[Int] = testList.map{ currentChar =>
    if (currentChar == '(') 1
    else if (currentChar == ')') -1
    else 0
}
    

def foldOp(currentTotal: Int, newValue: Int) = {
    if (currentTotal < 0) {
        currentTotal
    } else {
        currentTotal + newValue
    }
}

val initialValue: Int = 0

val sumResult: Int = mappedList.foldLeft(initialValue)(foldOp)
    
val isBalanced: Boolean = sumResult == 0
    // true
```

As a function this might look something like:

```scala
def isBalanced( charList: List[Char] ): Boolean = {
    def mapChar( char: Char): Int = {
        if (char == '(') 1
        else if (char == ')') -1
        else 0
    }
    def foldOp(currentTotal: Int, newValue: Int) = {
        if (currentTotal < 0) {
            currentTotal
        } else {
            currentTotal + newValue
        }
    }
        
    val charToIntList: List[Int] = charList.map(mapChar)
    val sum: Int = charToIntList.foldLeft(0)(foldOp)
    sum == 0
}
```

Pattern-matching is also a great functional tool:

```scala
def isBalanced( charList: List[Char] ): Boolean = {
    charList.map{
        case '(' => 1
        case ')' => -1
        case _ => 0
    }.foldLeft(0)(foldOp) == 0
}
```

My goal here is not to provide you with an answer that you should copy/paste, rather, I would like to share my own approach and interpretation of how to express a solution to such a problem. My goal is to hopefully inspire a solution or to give a peek into the many different ways to solve a problem.

Now, that being said, this can absolutely be done recursively:

```scala
def isBalanced( charList: List[Char], runningTotal: Int = 0 ): Boolean = {
    if (runningTotal < 0) {
        false
    }
    charList match {
            // Base Case (1) Empty List, return whether or not the total is 0
        case Nil => runningTotal == 0
            // Recursive Case head char and the rest of the list
        case headChar :: rest =>
            val mappedValue: Int = headChar match {
                case '(' => 1
                case ')' => -1
                case _ => 0
            }
            isBalanced(rest, runningTotal + mappedValue)
    }
}
```

<s>Finally, I would also like to point out `filter`. For small lists, this is a rather verbose way of doing things, but if the list is reaaaaaaaally big, this will cut the size of the elements to check (perhaps better suited to a more complex use-case)</s>

As Luis pointed out, `collect` is way better for this, it will apply the partial function (matching) [syntactic sugar for `_ match { case ... }`] like map, but for any case that isn't defined, it will not be collected.

```scala
def isBalanced( charList: List[Char] ): Boolean = {
    val mappedValues: List[Int] = charList.collect{
        case '(' => 1
        case ')' => -1
    }
    mappedValues.foldLeft(initialValue)(foldOp)
}
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you :) I think I've addressed both your points

Comment: Now the _"only problem"_ is that this is suboptimal, creating intermediate values and not stopping as soon as the algorithm knows the answer will be not balanced. Making recursion the _"best"_ (TM) way to solve this problem ;)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your input, the goal was not to be optimal. The goal is to be clear and explicit. The vals are meant to inform the reader of what that data represents. It is an explicit exercise for the explicit purpose of being explicit and to impart ideas and concepts commonly found in functional programming.

Comment: As with anything, experience comes with practice. Recognizing patterns and how to apply things to those patterns is a fundamental part of learning Scala and for learning functional programming in general. When it comes to sharing code, I believe very strongly in the "each line should do one thing" principle. It makes debugging far easier, and it makes bugged code easier to share and understand. When debugging or learning, to understand the explicit way to do things will lead to an implicit understanding of how to do them smarter.

Comment: Sure and starting with recursion is the very first step to understand more advanced things like `map` which is implemented in terms of `foldLeft` which is implemented in terms of recursion. - Note this question comes from one of the very firs exercises from the very first week from the very first course of **Scala** by Martin. - Keeping things simple is better for OP who is just starting to even understand expressions ;)

Comment: Sure, tell a professor with a master in pedagogy how to teach the language :) - In any case, agree to disagree. I am sure I do not have all the answers in the universe and that is why I marked the words `only problem` and `best` in my previous comment with quotes and in italic, because they are not absolute. - You know, there is probably also a reason why the creator of the language decided to teach some topics in some order, and why most books and tutorials follow the same order. - In any case, the question wasn't even on-topic for SO in the first place, which is kind of sad.

Comment: BTW, note that I am not saying the answer is wrong _per se_, or that OP would not understand it _(and even less imply that he / she is dumb)_. I am just saying that the question was very specific and that in any case OP is required to answer the problem using recursion. I am not even sure if by that time they already know pattern matching or not.